# Debian jessie, primus and 32-bit applications

Tags: debian, 32bit, steam, optimus

Whenever i start a 32-bit program aka. 386 with primusrun on debian jessie (be it steam or any of it's 32-bit games), i get a following error:

```
wv@localhost:~$ primusrun steam
Running Steam on debian 8 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

I have bumblebee-nvidia, primus, primus-libs and primus-libs:i386 installed. Swrast driver is present in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/dri/ directory.
Both 32 and 64 bit libGL.so.1* are present in the system.
What could be wrong here? Has anybody met and successfully resolved a similar problem?
64 bit games run through steam work fine (using launch options primusrun %command%). This occures to 32 bit games only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the solution. Something's completely wrong with all those multiple libGL.so.1 lib files around the system. So solution for this is performing next commands as root:

```
apt-get purge bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs primus-libs:i386
apt-get purge glx-diversions
apt-get purge libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
apt-get autoremove
```

Wait some time until everything is deleted (this might also delete skype and/or some other 32-bit programs if they depend on 32-bit libgl1-mesa-glx, don't worry, it's easy to restore them. In my case it was only skype)

```
apt-get update
apt-get install bumblebee-nvidia primus primus-libs primus-libs:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```

All the symlinks are recreated, all libraries' versions are correct, and everything works as intended.